# Strange error when using sparse matrices and glmnet

Tags: r, matrix

I'm getting a weird error when training a glmnet regression.

```
invalid class "dgCMatrix" object: length(Dimnames[[2]])' must match Dim[2]
```

It only happens occasionally, and perhaps only under larger datasets.

I'm not sure whether it's consistent it happens given a certain dataset.

Any clues?

Comment: length(Dimnames[[2]])' must match Dim[2] is a very general error, which could imply that you're referencing variables which are improperly named (for instance).  I'm guessing that you will need to provide more detail; maybe try debugging this and inspecting the elements before the error.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the particulars of this packages, John Chambers "Software for Data Analsys" (2008, Springer) has a good discussion on debugging, for example via

```
> options(error=recover)
```

which may be of help here.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting the same error while using family='binomial'. Turns out I had too few events/cases in my response variable. Using nfold=10 in cv.glmnet, I would get the error if my binary response [0,1] occured less than ~2% of the time. I recommend having your script check for this scenario and use glmnet when true. You won't get the benefit of the x validation for selecting lambda though.

Answer (score 0):

Need to clarify the above. I had this problem when using cv.glmnet(). By identifying those instances where there are too few cases, I used glmnet() instead. You lose the benefit of the cross validation (i.e. estimating lambda), but it will complile.

Comment: You can append to your previous answer (click edit at the bottom left side of the answer). After you're done, can you please remove this last "answer"? Thank you.